# Convert custom formatted string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert a string into a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse("20150620 800", out newDate);
```

The default value (`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`) is returned, how can this be correctly converted?

Comment: your string format does not match the datetime format. you should convert it manually

Comment: Thats not a standard date time string, so you need to define what the actual format *is*, then use `ParseExact`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to take a custom string and convert it,

According to MSDN:

> If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or
>   time separators (such as "yyyyMMdd HHmm"), use the invariant culture
>   for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format
>   specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format
>   pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form,
>   "H".

This conversion is not possible, unless you change your input data.

You would expect this to work: (This really confused me for a bit while writing this)

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20150620 800", "yyyyMMdd Hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But since `H` must be in its widest form, it must be `HH`, as it thinks `80` is out of range for the hour measurement. You will need to add a space between `8` and `00`, or add a `0` before `8`.

These solutions will work:

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20150620 8 00", "yyyyMMdd H mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20150620 0800", "yyyyMMdd HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you cannot change this input data (eg, from a database), just perform a substring operation to insert a space between the minutes and hours so .NET can tell which is which:

```
var text = "20150620 800";
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(text.Insert(text.Length - 2, " "), "yyyyMMdd H mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: it feels better to use the second solution. and just put `text.Replace(" "," 0")` instead of insert. just feels better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime.ParseExact(newDate,"yyyyMMdd Hmm", new DateFormatInfo());
```

Should work. Double check the .Net date format string reference to make sure it is what you want.

Comment: This doesn't work, I came up with the same solution but can't figure out why. `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` Even through creating a DateTime with the correct date and calling `ToString` with that format returns the result OP wants.